# Does a portable pthread_sleep() function exist?

Tags: c, pthreads, sleep

I'm writing an ANSI C application that will be built on both Linux and Windows.

I built the pthread 2.9.1 library for Windows and all works fine.

The problem is that I can't find the function:  pthread_sleep()

I also looked around for that function but it seems that it doesn't exist.

Without that function my code will have to call Sleep() on Windows and sleep() on Linux but that's exactly what I don't want.

Thanks,
Enrico Migliore

Comment: If you need your thread to sleep, you should not be using threads.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't find the function: pthread_sleep()

No, you wouldn't, since pthreads does not provide such a function.  And why would it?  There is nothing specific to the pthreads API about making a thread sleep, and genuine POSIX platforms all have a variety of other mechanisms, including `sleep()`, to make a thread sleep.  Not that making threads of a multithreaded program sleep (as opposed to *block*) is very often a good or reasonable thing to do, anyway.

> Without that function my code will have to call Sleep() on Windows and sleep() on Linux but that's exactly what I don't want.

I'm inclined to think that you don't really want to call a platform-agnostic alternative either.  But the traditional approach to handling such issues of using various platform-specific functions to accomplish a common goal is to use a conditionally-defined macro or a wrapper function with condtionally-defined implementation to hide the platform-specific bits.  For example,

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
// Sleep() expects an argument in milliseconds
#define SLEEP(time) Sleep((time) * 1000)
#else
// sleep() expects an argument in seconds
#define SLEEP(time) sleep(time)
#endif
```

For your particular case, however, there is also the possibility of calling a function with a user-specifiable timeout that you expect always to expire.  Pthreads does provide functions you could use for that, such as `pthread_cond_timedwait()`.  You could write a sleep function with that, without any conditional compilation.  For example,

```
int my_sleep(long milliseconds) {
    static pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    static pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    int rval = 0;

    if (milliseconds > 0) {
        struct timespec time;

        rval = timespec_get(&time, TIME_UTC);
        // ... handle any error ...
        time.tv_nsec += (milliseconds % 1000) * 1000000;
        time.tv_sec += milliseconds / 1000 + time.tv_nsec / 1000000;
        time.tv_nsec %= 1000000;

        rval = pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (rval != 0) {
            // handle error ...
        } else {
            // The loop handles spurrious wakepups
            do {
                rval = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &time);  // expects ETIMEDOUT
            } while (rval == 0);
            if (rval != ETIMEDOUT) {
                // handle error ...
            }
            rval = pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);  // THIS MUST NOT BE SKIPPED
            // ... handle any error ...
        }
    }

    return rval;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll test the function you're proposing: my_sleep()